# jQuery Nested Tabs without UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

Trying to set up nested tabs *without* jQuery UI.

I have the top level tabs working fine, however, not the inner tabs - index seems to be getting confused between top level and the inner tabs.

```
$(function() {
      $('#application-tabs nav a').on('click', function() {
        show_content($(this).index());
      });

      show_content(0);

      function show_content(index) {
        // Make the content visible
        $('#application-tabs .content.visible').removeClass('visible');
        $('#application-tabs .content:nth-of-type(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('visible');

        // Set the tab to selected
        $('#application-tabs nav a.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $('#application-tabs nav a:nth-of-type(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('selected');
      }
    });
$(function() {
      $('.application-sub-tabs nav.sub a').on('click', function() {
        show_content_sub($(this).index());
      });

      show_content_sub(0);

      function show_content_sub(index) {
        // Make the content visible
        $('.application-sub-tabs .content-sub.visible-sub').removeClass('visible-sub');
        $('.application-sub-tabs .content-sub:nth-of-type(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('visible-sub');

        // Set the tab to selected
        $('.application-sub-tabs nav.sub a.selected-sub').removeClass('selected-sub');
        $('.application-sub-tabs nav.sub a:nth-of-type(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('selected-sub');
      }
    });
```

Here is a JSFiddle of where I am on it: https://jsfiddle.net/81ebq0Lw/5/

Any thoughts on getting the inner tabs functioning independently of the top tabs?

I'm sure there are more efficient ways of setting this up...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two nav tags. you need to be specific with selectors. 
check this fiddle.

```
<nav id="test">   and  
$('#application-tabs #test a').on('click', function()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8eLmdj0/

new: https://jsfiddle.net/e8eLmdj0/2/

Comment: Thank you - that makes perfect sense why that was getting confused. How would I go about setting the first sub tab active, each time a top level tab gets selected?

Comment: For instance - with fewer sub tabs under tab 2, selecting sub tab 3 in either tab 1 or 3, then returning to tab 2 - none of the sub tabs are active. https://jsfiddle.net/e8eLmdj0/1/

Comment: Thank you @techLove - really appreciate your help!